# Parameterize tag value inside XML contained in the parameter at runtime in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I saved the whole XML in a DB table and am fetching the XML in JDBC sampler and using it in HTTP sampler. I want to parameterize a value inside a particular tag value inside this fetched xml at runtime. Could someone tell me how to do that. Thanks in advance

In http sampler ==> post body

```
xmldoc = ${xmlfromdb}
```

Here am able to fetch the whole XML and I can submit it successfully. How to parameterize a tag value inside this fetched xml at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via scripting like:

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   String body = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
   body = body.replace("Original Tag Value", "New Tag Value");
   sampler.getArguments().removeArgument(0);
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("", body, "");
   ```

`sampler` is a pre-defined variable available for Beanshell (and some other Test Elements) which stands for parent Sampler instance and in case of HTTP Request it's [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html). See JavaDoc for more information on available methods and fields and [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using JMeter and Java API from Beanshell test elements inside JMeter script.